# Laravel Project, access a specific view

Tags: php, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a laravel, angularjs - bootstrap project, where I have many forms.
Every form has its own view :
CategoriesView for example.
In this view I defined 3 variables,categories, newcategories and updatecategories.

newcategories shows me  a form where I can add a new category.
updatecategories load a form where I can edit a specific category.

When I load the view, categories load using a table like this:

```
                               [newCategoryButton]

#   |    Description  | 
1   |    food         | pencilIcon
2   |    beverage     | pencilIcon
```

If the user clicks new category button, newcategories load (newcategories =true),
if he clicks on pencil, it goes to updatecategories with categoryid (updatecategories = true).

My question is, In another form, i made a button where the user  can add a new category, but how can I load directly the new category form, without passing in categories(the main view page where the user get the list of categories)

Comment: if i get it correctly you can create another form with modal or however you want it and display it with the click of the button, and you can send the request with ajax.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating another form.

Comment: Then you cant, if the form is in another view there is no reasonable way to load it.. you can load the view in an iframe within the view you already are but that's no good practice. if there is no rule not to create the form a suggest you just create another one

Comment: Yes I have now the ifarme method, but that's not professional and it's not a solution it can load the main view (categories) then the user has to click on new category